# NSString length limit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

How can I limit the length of a NSString? I would like to keep it below to equal to 100 characters/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the sample of fundamental manipulate string size.

#### Declare maximum string length:

```
int max = 5;
```

#### Let's assume have list of strings in array:

```
NSArray *strs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"My Little Puppy", @"Yorkerz", nil];
```

#### Loop Operation:

```
[strs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *str, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (str.length > max)
        //get a modified string
        str = [str substringToIndex:str.length-(str.length-max)];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
}];
```

#### Results:

```
"My Li" and "Yorke"
```

Hope, I understood right from your question.

Comment: The loop throws an error in ARC.  You need to set the *str variable as __strong e.g.  for (NSString __strong *str in strs)

Answer (score 2):

Then you will have to check for the `length:` before you put into the NSString. Then if the length is more than 100, you use `substringToIndex:`

Comment: what about memory management?
str = [str substringToIndex:100]; is this valid? or do I need to use copy?

Comment: that's valid, I think it will create another instance for substring and get it back to you. also, remember that str is autoreleased already. You should retain it if you want to keep it for long

Comment: Correction: `str` *may* be autoreleased already. If you previously wrote `str = [[NSString alloc] init];` or similar, it certainly isn't!

But yes, assuming you're not leaking `str`, what you wrote is valid.

Comment: @andyvn22: ops, it is my mistake, I didn't see that he uses the same variable for the substring and the main string

Answer (score 0):

Then do not add more than 100 characters.

If you have an existing string that you wish to shorten, then you can use the `substringToIndex:` method to create a shorter string.